# Arrays are not posting to php

Tags: php, html, post

#### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_URL ?>modal.css" /> 
   <form id="postinfo" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="technician" value="<?php echo $technician; ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="custnum" value="<?php echo    htmlentities(serialize($customerNum)); ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="meternum" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($meterNumbers)); ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="remcred" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($remCreditArray)); ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="visitdate" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($dateArray)); ?>">
        <a href ="<?php echo PROCESS_URL; ?>create_maint_token_excel.php" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGE_URL ?>Excel.png" name="Print Excel" title="Print Excel" alt="Print Excel" /></a>

   </form>
```

#### PHP

```
$customerNum = unserialize($_POST['custnum']);
$meterNumbers = unserialize($_POST['meternum']);
$remCreditArray = unserialize($_POST['remcred']);
$dateArray = unserialize($_POST['visitdate']);
$technician = ($_POST['technician']);
```

I have tried numerous ways of posting these arrays to a php page but the page keeps telling me that `custnum`, `meternum`, `remcred` and `visitdate` are undefined.

I have tried using a form action and post, I have tried to use a piece of javascript and I keep getting the same problem, why is this not posting?

I have also tried using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` on php page to no avail.

Comment: Check `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Don't guess, debug: hit `Ctrl+U` in your browser (or use its developer tools) to see actual generated HTML; use `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's received by PHP.

Comment: Have you tried session variables?

Comment: Not the cause for your error. But **you are not closing the input tags**.

Comment: Uhm, are you trying to submit your form by clicking on the link to `create_maint_token_excel.php`?

Comment: agree with mithunsatheesh, this is invalid HTML as you are mixing HTML4/5 and XHTML. Your `action=""` attribute is empty, which it should not be.

Comment: I'd suggest using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` rather than `serialize()` / `unserialize()`. You probably don't even need them as separate fields; just output on single json string into a single hidden field. Alternatively, do you really need to be putting the data onto a form at all, if the next thing you do it read them all back unchanged? Maybe storing them in the session might be more appropriate?

Comment: @ErichNiemand - Do you really prefer to rewrite your logic, use sessions for no apparent reason and make you app unsuitable for multiple-tab browsing... to simply stop guessing and gather some basic debugging info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href ="<?php echo PROCESS_URL; ?>create_maint_token_excel.php" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">
```

This will not work, the submit will go into nirvana and you will be taken to the PHP page without the variables. You are doing two requests at once and your browser will go to the one without the form variables.

Try changing your form to this:

```
<form id="postinfo" action="<?php echo PROCESS_URL; ?>create_maint_token_excel.php" method="POST">
```

And your Link to this:

```
<a href ="#" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">
```

This should submit the form correctly without following the link.

Alternatively use a propper `<input type="submit" />` button, you can add the image to it with CSS.

Comment: @ErichNiemand If you see it as the solution to your problem mark the answer as accepted. This will increase your reputation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a form submit button, rather than making life complax with javascript? But first.. Debug, check what is actually in your hidden input.

Better would probably be to keep all these details on the server in a table called maintenance, and only pass the record ID to the webpage. A lot less info that the user can tamper with.

Also, you can just use a regulaer weblink to link to load the next page with the variables in the url (read [GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)), unless there is some input from the user which requires a form, which we do not see.

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying as,

```
<?php foreach ($customerNum as $item): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="custnum[]" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"/>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

In `php` you could get as,

```
$customerNum = $_POST['custnum'];
```

And use,

```
<a href ="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="technician" value="<?php echo $technician; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="custnum" value="<?php echo    htmlentities(serialize($customerNum)); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="meternum" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($meterNumbers)); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="remcred" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($remCreditArray)); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="visitdate" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($dateArray)); ?>">
    <a href ="<?php echo PROCESS_URL; ?>create_maint_token_excel.php" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">
            <img src="<?php echo IMAGE_URL ?>Excel.png" name="Print Excel" title="Print Excel" alt="Print Excel" /></a>
```

just replace  to inpuit type submit or you can use type image and add action url to action tag of form then you would get values by post method like below exa

Comment: And submitting a form with JavaScript does not work because...?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified test case:

```
<form id="postinfo" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="1">
    <a href="http://www.google.es" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

If you hit "Submit" you'll see that your browser will open the `href` URL before your JavaScript code has any chance to make a POST request to the `action` URL.

You'll possibly want one of these:

```
<!-- No action href -->
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">Submit</a>

<!-- Cancel click event -->
<a href="http://www.google.es" onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit(); return false;">Submit</a>

<!-- No link at all -->
<div onclick="document.getElementById('postinfo').submit();">Submit</div>
```

**Side note:** If you use PHP serialization, beware of [object injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection).